# spresense wire.writeについて

Tags: spresense

SPRESENEに拡張ボードを接続し、Arduio IDE on WindowsでのI2C通信を行おうとしています。

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define OLED_ADDR 0x3C

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(OLED_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();

}
```

Wire.writeで以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SPRESENSE\hardware\spresense\1.0.0\cores\spresense/Print.h:53:12: note: candidate: size_t Print::write(const char*)

     size_t write(const char *str) {
            ^

exit status 1
call of overloaded 'write(int)' is ambiguous
```

おかしなところがあればご指摘願います。

Comment: [API のリファレンス](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite)を眺めてみますと、`a value to send as a single byte` などと書かれていますので、`Wire.write(byte(0x00));` とするのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API のリファレンス](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite)を眺めてみますと、`a value to send as a single byte` などと書かれていますので、`Wire.write(byte(0x00));` とするのではないでしょうか。

-- [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48665/spresense-wire-write%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/48838#comment50545_48665)より

Comment: metropolisさんの回答で上手くいきました。ありがとうございます。
この時0x00ではbyteが必要で0x40では必要ない疑問が出来ましたがちょっと調べてみます。